# Objective-c NSMutableDictionary set with an array keep empty

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, dictionary, nsmutabledictionary

I'm new here, but I use to read this site when I need something, but today, I can't find an answer to my question.

I'll try to explain my problem with enough details.

I need to add an array into a NSMutableDictionary at a specific key. The key added into it is correctly up, but my dictionary value keep empty. Here is my code :

```
dictionarySection = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:arraySectionValues forKeys:arraySectionKeys];
dictionaryClip = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:[arraySectionKeys count]];

NSArray *tabSection = [dictionarySection allKeys];
id key,value;
for (int j=0; j<tabSection.count; j++)
{
    array = [NSMutableArray array];
    key = [tabSection objectAtIndex: j];
    value = [dictionarySection objectForKey: key];
    //NSLog (@"Key: %@ for value: %@", key, value);
    for (SMXMLElement *clip in [books childrenNamed:@"clip"]) {
        if([[clip valueWithPath:@"categorie"] isEqualToString:value]){
            [array addObject:[clip valueWithPath:@"titre"]];
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"Test array %@",array);
    [dictionaryClip setObject:array forKey:key];
    [array removeAllObjects];
    NSLog(@"Test dictionary %@",dictionaryClip);
}
```

Here the NSLog result :

```
2015-07-15 14:34:48.272 test[15533:390301] Test array (
"CDS : ITV Philippe Dunoyer",
"FLASH INFO NCI : crise des banques",
"Les Roussettes sont-elles dangereuses ?",
"Flash infos banques gr\U00e8ve",
"CDS : ITV Paul Langevin",
"CDS : ITV Valls",
"CDS : ITV Victor Tutugoro",
"CDS : ITV Roch Wamytan",
"NCGLAN 20",
"Flash Info : dispositif anti-d\U00e9linquance"
)
2015-07-15 14:34:48.273 test[15533:390301] key : 0
2015-07-15 14:34:48.273 test[15533:390301] Test dictionary {
    0 =     (
    );
}
```

As we can see, the array is filled, the dictionary's key is correct, but the array isn't into my dictionary.

How may I suppose to fill my dictionary with this array?

Thanks a lot guy(s) for answer(s) :)

Ps : excuse my english :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling **removeAllObjects:** method for same instance of array which you are passing in dictionary so it objects are being removed in stored array. Try to pass that array's copy or a new instance of array with same objects.

**Example:**

```
[dictionaryClip setObject:[array copy] forKey:key];
```

Comment: Perfect I got what I wanted :) Thanks a lot !!! I'm too low in reputation to give you a point :( But thanks any way ;)

Comment: Glad to help you!
@vadian told you same but because you are new programmer so I explained a bit more. :) Happy Coding and you can give me points later.

Answer (score 0):

In Objective-C arrays are reference types.

The method `setObject:forKey:` puts a pointer to the array into the dictionary, the array is not copied.

If you remove all objects from the array, they also disappear in the dictionary

Comment: Ok thanks ! I didn't think about this ! I'll try with an other way so ... If you have an idea to help me it could be nice :)

Comment: @Nicolas Perhaps just make a copy of the array? `[dictionaryClip setObject:[array copy] forKey:key];` That is probably the simplest solution, and after you can do whatever you want with the original array.